# Parsing Json data from asp.net webservice and populating it in asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

i am trying to populate an asp.net dropdownlist returned as JSON from my webservice.

**WebService**

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetActiveDepositAccountsForLoanAlert(string customerId)
    {
        var data = BusinessLayer.SMS.SmsSetup.GetActiveDepositAccountsForLoanAlert(customerId.ToLong());
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
        return json;
    }
```

The webservice returns

> [{"AccountNumber":"NS-0000092"},{"AccountNumber":"6MR-0000002"},{"AccountNumber":"1YFD-0000007"}]

I am calling the data from ajax call and populating it to my dropdownlist.

**Ajax call**

```js
 function GetActiveDepositAccounts(customerrId) {
            var customerId = $('#CustomerIdHiddenField').val();
            var data = { customerId: $('#CustomerIdHiddenField').val() };
            var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebMethods/Misc.asmx/GetActiveDepositAccountsForLoanAlert",
                data: json_data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
               
        }
        function OnSuccess(r) {
            var depositRadioList = $("[id*=DepositAccountDropDownList]");
            depositRadioList.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
                depositRadioList.append('<option>' + r.d[i] + '</option>');
            }
        }
```

The data gets populated in json.In my dropdown i only want the accountnumber as 
NS-0000092.I am getting the whole json in my dropdown.i have searched and seen lots of question with this Json parse thing in here.But couldnt get hold of this.It isnt that i didnt tried,I am newbie,so before marking this as duplicate,please for once have a look at the code.Thank you.

Comment: `r.d[i]` is an object with one property and you want the value of that property. It's not like you haven't done something similar in your script already... (and no, this is not a [JSON](http://json.org) problem. `r` is already parsed and therefor an object)

Comment: @Andreas Help Appreciated sir.

Comment: ```r.d[i].AccountNumber```

You might want to throw a ```debugger``` in the start of your ```OnSuccess()``` so you can step through and see what's going on.

Comment: @MarkCooper i did tried this sir..what i get is undefined.

Comment: @OLDMONK throw a line with ```debugger;``` on it in the beginning of your ```OnSuccess``` function. This will allow you to see and  manipulate your state in real time. In your browser's console you can explore what things actually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't shake the feeling that because your `GetActiveDepositAccountsForLoanAlert` is returning a string and not an object, r.d is being seen as a string. Try one of 2 things. Either:

1. Change your method signature to return data type and don't use the JavaScriptSerializer. or,
2. In your OnSuccess function, add `var data = JSON.parse(r.d)` and use that variable in your for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..both of them worked.1- Changed my method and signature and returning xml worked.and 2- OnSuccess function like you said,that worked too..Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

### Single Object Returned

If by "*whole json*", you mean you are getting a single `{"AccountNumber":"6MR-0000002"}` per option -- try outputting the value of the target AccountNumber object (e.g. `r.d[i].AccountNumber` or `r.d[i]["AccountNumber"]`).

### Modified Function

```
    var depositRadioList = $("[id*=DepositAccountDropDownList]");
        depositRadioList.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
            depositRadioList.append('<option>' + r.d[i].AccountNumber + '</option>');
        }
```

### Array of Objects Returned

If the result per option is an entire AccountNumber array of objects, you'll need to loop through your `r` object until you get to the list of Account Number objects.

Take a look at my [Example JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyler_crawford/jm7184he/). There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but to present the principle, I've laid out nested loops to get you into the list of object values that you need for your `<select></select>`.

I'm using the JQuery $.each() method, but you can use the `for` loop. I recommend just using one or the other for consistency. If the data set is really large, `for` loops have better performance.

Comment: By whole i mean this [{"AccountNumber":"NS-0000092"},{"AccountNumber":"6MR-0000002"},{"AccountNumber":"1YFD-0000007"}]

Comment: Hmmm. Can you provide the output of a single option value? As in, does it look like: `{"AccountNumber":"6MR-0000002"}`?

Comment: Oh -- that means `r.d` is a parent/containing object and you have to dig down one more level. Add a for or $.each() loop to iterate through `r.d`. Will update my answer to show example.

Comment: Any example sir?

Comment: Was making an example snippet -- just added the JS for now.

Comment: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Comment: Appreciate your time sir..i am still getting the same error..my r object when i console.log,it looks like this-- "[{"AccountNumber":"NS-0000012"}]"

Comment: @OLDMONK Sorry, I had to do some work at work. =P Just knocked up a quick Fiddle to show what I mean about looping through your object. (This of course is assuming the object structure since I actually don't know what the r object looks like.) Updated my answer with the Fiddle.

Comment: @OLDMONK Oh okay then -- So if you are only getting a single array, you only need to loop once.  Not sure where the `r.d` came from. =P 

Updated / forked my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tyler_crawford/17ksz7t7/ Does something like this work?

Comment: Earlier it was a list of undefined..now thers one...sorry to bug you sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164705/discussion-between-tyler-crawford-and-oldmonk).